# Demonstrating orthonormality for wave functions for ground state and excited state of He

Tags: quantum-chemistry

> The electron configuration of the ground state $\ce{He}$ atom is $\ce{1s^2}$, and the excited state configuration under study is $\ce{1s^2 2s^1}$. Show that these states are *orthonormal*, i.e.,
>
> $$\langle\Psi_0 \vert\Psi_0\rangle = 1$$
>
> $$\langle\Psi_1 \vert\Psi_1\rangle = 1$$
>
> $$\langle\Psi_0 \vert\Psi_1\rangle = 0$$

I start off by defining the wave functions as Slater determinants,

$$
\Psi_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{vmatrix}
\phi_1(1)\alpha(1) & \phi_1(1)\beta(1) \\
\phi_1(2)\alpha(2) & \phi_1(2)\beta(2)
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$$
\Psi_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{vmatrix}
\phi_1(1)\alpha(1) & \phi_2(1)\beta(1) \\
\phi_1(2)\alpha(2) & \phi_2(2)\beta(2)
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I am able to show that the wave functions are normalized, but I have trouble showing that they are also orthogonal. I get that $\langle\Psi_0 \vert\Psi_1\rangle = 1$. I set up the integral over all coordinates, carry out the multiplications, and add together the terms that are equivalent due to indistinguishable electrons (identical when all coordinates are interchanged). I end up with the expression

$$
\int d\tau \left[  \phi_1^*(1)\alpha(1)\phi_2^*(2)\beta(2)\phi_1(1)\alpha(1)\phi_2(2)\beta(2) - \phi_1^*(1)\alpha(1)\phi_2^*(2)\beta(2)\phi_1(2)\alpha(2)\phi_2(1)\beta(1)   \right]
$$

where $d\tau$ represents all coordinates. Separating the spin coordinates from the spatial coordinates, I get that

$$
\langle\Psi_0 \vert\Psi_1\rangle = \\
\sum_{m_{s1}=-1/2}^{1/2} \sum_{m_{s2}=-1/2}^{1/2} \alpha(1)\alpha(1)\beta(2)\beta(2) \cdot \langle\phi_1(1) \vert\phi_1(1)\rangle \cdot \langle\phi_2(2) \vert\phi_2(2)\rangle \\
- \sum_{m_{s1}=-1/2}^{1/2} \sum_{m_{s2}=-1/2}^{1/2} \alpha(1)\alpha(2)\beta(2)\beta(1) \cdot \langle\phi_1(1) \vert\phi_2(1)\rangle \cdot \langle\phi_2(2) \vert\phi_1(2)\rangle \\
= 1 - 0 = 1
$$

The first term reduces to $1$, I find, while the second term reduces to $0$. To get $\langle\Psi_0 \vert\Psi_1\rangle = 0$, either both terms need to be $1$, or both terms need to be $0$. Something must be incorrect. Is there some obvious flaw in my derivations?

Comment: page 8 of the pdf at this link discusses this problem, but it has been so long since I did this that I don't really remember how to do the math. https://www.chem.tamu.edu/rgroup/hughbanks/courses/673/handouts/antisymmetry.pdf Obviously the gist is that $1s^12s^1$ to $1s^2$ is a forbidden transition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First prove a well-known fact that any two spin orbitals $\psi_i$ and $\psi_j$ are orthogonal if the corresponding spatial orbitals from which they are constructed are themselves orthogonal.

- For two spin orbitals constructed from two different spatial orbitals orthogonality follows from orthogonality of spatial orbitals regardless of spin components.
- For two spin orbitals constructed from the same spatial orbital orthogonality follows from orthogonality of spin functions.

Then you can work with spin orbitals to (re)establish a well-known result that for two Slater determinants differ in just one spin orbital, the overlap integral $\langle \Psi_0 \vert \Psi_1 \rangle$ is zero. 
$$
\Psi_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{vmatrix}
\psi_1(1) & \psi_2(1) \\
\psi_1(2) & \psi_2(2)
\end{vmatrix} \, ,
\quad
\Psi_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{vmatrix}
\psi_1(1) & \psi_3(1) \\
\psi_1(2) & \psi_3(2)
\end{vmatrix} \, ,
$$
where
$$
\psi_1(1) = \phi_1(1) \alpha(1) \, ,
\quad
\psi_2(1) = \phi_1(1) \beta(1) \, ,
\quad
\psi_3(1) = \phi_2(1) \beta(1) \, .
$$
Algebraically, it is very easy to show that,
$$
  \langle \Psi_0 \vert \Psi_1 \rangle =
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \langle \psi_1(1) \psi_2(2) - \psi_2(1) \psi_1(2) \vert \psi_1(1) \psi_3(2) - \psi_3(1) \psi_1(2) \rangle \\
  = \frac{1}{2} \Big(
    \langle \psi_1(1) \psi_2(2) \vert \psi_1(1) \psi_3(2) \rangle
  - \langle \psi_1(1) \psi_2(2) \vert \psi_3(1) \psi_1(2) \rangle \\
  - \langle \psi_2(1) \psi_1(2) \vert \psi_1(1) \psi_3(2) \rangle
  + \langle \psi_2(1) \psi_1(2) \vert \psi_3(1) \psi_1(2) \rangle \Big) \\
  = \frac{1}{2} \Big(
    \langle \psi_1(1) \vert \psi_1(1) \rangle
    \langle \psi_2(2) \vert \psi_3(2) \rangle 
  - \langle \psi_1(1) \vert \psi_3(1) \rangle
    \langle \psi_2(2) \vert \psi_1(2) \rangle \\
  - \langle \psi_2(1) \vert \psi_1(1) \rangle 
    \langle \psi_1(2) \vert \psi_3(2) \rangle
  + \langle \psi_2(1) \vert \psi_3(1) \rangle
    \langle \psi_1(2) \vert \psi_1(2) \rangle \Big) \\
  = \frac{1}{2} \Big(c_1 \cdot 0 - 0 \cdot 0 - 0 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot c_1 \Big) = 0 \, .
$$
In the case when spin orbitals are normalized (to one) $c_1 = 1$, but it is not required here: the overlap integral will vanish for spin orbitals that are just orthogonal and not necessarily normalized (to one) as well.